# Filter table columns (not rows) on selecting an option from a dropdown select in Vue-tables-2

Tags: vue.js, html-table, datatables, css-tables, vue-tables-2

I have a table with numerous columns. The columns can be grouped into a few categories. I want to filter the columns by their categories.

For Example:

`Categories   Africa                Asia               South America`

`Columns     |Nigeria|Tanzania|Mali|China|Russia|India|Brazil|Peru|Chile|`

The dropdown select will have the Categories `Africa Asia South America`

On selecting Asia, the table will now look like this:

`Categories   Asia`
`Columns     |China|Russia|India|`

On selecting the category, all the other columns not belonging to the selected category should be hidden.

I already have the component containing the categories placed next to the main filter. All I need now is the logic to hide the categories on category select, either that or a way to tap into the built in `columnsDropdown` option to achieve this functionality.

Help appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You referred to `columnsDropdown` but we don't know how you've chosen to implement it because there's no code in your post.  Is there an object somewhere that links categories to columns?

Comment: Based on the `datatables` tag in your question, take a look at this demo from the DataTables web site: [Show / hide columns dynamically](https://datatables.net/examples/api/show_hide.html). And for more advanced examples, see this section of the site: [Column visibility examples](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/column_visibility/index.html).